# travelling to canada with 2 passports

Tags: passports

I am a South African travelling to Canada with 2 passports. Passport one is expiring 2 days after I leave Canada and has a valid visa in it.  Passport 2 is a new passport. is this okay

Comment: Are they both South African passports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canada does not have a rule requiring that a passport be valid for any specific length of time, just valid for your stay. So passport one would in fact be sufficient.

However in most cases a passport is invalidated when a new one is issued to the same person by the same country. If this is the case with yours then you will need to have both passport 2 present (for validity) and passport 1 (for the visa).

This assumes that you mean both passports are South African.